# Is it possible to prevent an application remove a file but allow it write on OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-permissions, mac-app-store, inode

I'm installing Xcode from Mac App Store but sadly fails every time near finish with

> Xcode failed to download
>
> Use the Purchases page to try again.

message.

Except once that I copied pkg inside  $TMPDIR../C/com.apple.appstore/497799835 before the App Store application auto deletes them while popping up an error dialog.

And the pkg is installable. I've successfully installed Xcode by the copied pkg before.

As I couldn't figure out why "Xcode failed to download" continues. And just got an error(again and again) after long time download is too sad. I'm wondering is there something I can do to prevent the auto-deleting?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening terminal and running `open $TMPDIR../C/` then delete the folder named com.apple.appstore while the app store window is completely closed. You may need to run `rm -rf $TMPDIR../C/com.apple.appstore` if you cannot right-click + delete the folder normally, but I DO NOT recommend running the rm command unless you know what you are doing. After the com.apple.appstore folder is gone, reboot the computer and it *should* be able to install normally.

This solved my issue when I had trouble downloading multiple apps on a poor connection. I'd paused the downloads and tried to restart them elsewhere. That was a bad decision.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for share. For this question I was wondering is there a way to backup the downloaded pkg before try any other solutions. Wasted many hours on redownloading.

Comment: There's a way with the command line, but I've no idea exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`ln the_original_folder/the_original_file the_backup_folder/the_backup_file` command do the trick.
Just hard link the file(s) you want to keep to another location. You would have one "shadow copy" left.